# Talend : Set up talend 5.6.1 to use java 1.7 jdk on macosx

Tags: java, neo4j, talend, bash, java-home

Using  Talend Big Data Studio.
Trying to use neo4jConnection for version 2.x.x, shows error "Component required Java 1.7"

I have setup JAVA_HOME path variable in my .bash_profile 
Also selected Preferences in Talend to point to Java 1.7 JRE.

Can anyone please let me know if this has worked for anyone?

Answer (score 1):

if you need run Talend with an specific java version, you can run it using the param "-vm".

i.e

```
 ./TOS_BD-linux-gtk-x86_64 -vm /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin
```

Just need to specify the [path to your JRE or JDK] after the -vm.